# Making a calculator using BISON

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc

This is my bison code. The problem is, when I input for example `4+3`, program detects a syntax error. But when I input `4 + 3`, that is the numbers are separated by a space, it computes and shows the result perfectly. Kindly hint where it might have gone wrong.

---

```
input:
 | input line
 ;

line: NEWLINE
 | expr NEWLINE     {cout << $1 << endl; $$ = $1;}
 ;
expr: term
 | expr PLUS term    {$$ = $1 + $3;}
 | expr MINUS term  {$$ = $1 - $3;}
 | expr LSHIFT term {checkedShifting($1, $3, &$$, true);}
 | expr RSHIFT term {checkedShifting($1, $3, &$$, false);}
 ;
term: factor
 | term MUL factor  {$$ = $1 * $3;}
 | term DIV factor  {checkedDivision($1, $3, &$$);}
 | term MOD factor  {checkedMod($1, $3, &$$);}
 ;
factor: NUMBER
   | LBRACE expr RBRACE     {$$ = $2;}
   | factor EXPONENT factor {$$ = pow($1, $3);}
   ;
```

---

Edit : This is my lex code:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6959725/

And the bison code:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6959727/

Comment: Is this all you have?

Comment: No, I just copied the grammar rules part here. Not sure if I should have put the entire lex and bison code here.

Comment: @sergio I have edited my question and attached the codes.

Comment: At a glance, seems that `4+3` should be tokenized as `{number}{signednumber}`, not `{number}{PLUS}{number}`

Comment: Do you need a special token for signed number, I wonder? I'd put this entity into parser.

Comment: Damn, that was a rather stupid mistake. Thanks for the hint. Let me work on it.

Comment: Repairing this issue solved the problems. Thanks @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Posted as an answer, so that you can give me some points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance, seems that 4+3 should be tokenized as `{number}{signednumber}`, not `{number}{PLUS}{number}`.

Also I think you shouldn't have a special token for signed number. Parser should figure out if this is an unary or binary plus/minus.